# Extract values from a string column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in a SQL Server database with a free text column called `Location`.

Examples of data in the column:

```
'There are three Bikes in the Shed'
'One car positioned in Garage last night'
```

I want to output into another column named `Result` that will look like this:

```
Bikes,Shed
Car,Garage
```

This done by finding using substring code (or suggested code) to find words of `Garage`, `Shed`, `Bikes`, and `Cars`.

The key words can be in any position, and may include variations of the original.

i will have to hard code the words to look for in the query

How can I do this please?

Comment: Where do you define the key words?

Comment: using a substring code, i need help with please to create the column result..please help

Comment: We don't know what a substring code is.

Comment: i would like to say substring([Location], 'Garage', 'Shed' , 'Bikes' ,'Cars') as [result] something like this ? ...is there code that can help me extract these words please

Comment: Yes, but are you hard-coding those words in the query? Or do they come from somewhere? Where?

Comment: You're on the [wrong end of this comic](https://xkcd.com/1425/). If you can solve this problem as described, you'll be most of the way to writing the world's first real English language processor.

Comment: What would the Result look like if the input were: "I moved the Bikes to the Garage from the Shed after the Car was gone"

Comment: bikes,shed,car would be the result  ...i need to hard code the words into the query please

Comment: @Joeysonic does your sql support regex ?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing a Colesce with case statement

but thanks team, appreciated all your ideas

Regards

Comment: This is not a very useful answer for future readers. If you've come to a solution but don't want to share the details about it, it might be best to just delete the question.